# Proper way to zip xlsx-file from directory using Info-Zip's Zip utility

Tags: c++, c, zip

I’m using Zip utility from the Info-Zip library to compress the tree of catalogs to get xlsx-file.
For that I’m using the next command:

```
zip -r -D res.xlsx source
```

source - contains the correct directory tree of the xlsx file.

But if you then look at the resulting file structure, the source directory will be included in the paths of all files and directories at the top level, and MS Office Excel will not be able to open this file. This is a well known problem. To avoid it zip.exe needs to be inside of the dest directory.

The problem is that I want to use the source code of this utility in my project, so this leads me to be unable to call my process, which will be responsible for compressing directories, to get xlsx files from these directories.

I’ve tried to find a place in the zip source code, where the parent catalog appending on the top-level happens. But seems
it is done implicitly.

Who can suggest how it can be done?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use a library such as libzip or zipios?

Comment: Using `zip` from a Bourne style shell, you could change directory before running `zip` with a wildcard, e.g.: `cd source ; zip -r -D ../res.xlsx "*" ; cd ..`.

Comment: @IanAbbott I'm using zip under Windows cmd and it is not included into system. I'm simply took zip source code and build .exe, so I can't use suggested by you command without having zip.exe inside of source folder. and I haven't researched other libraries besides this one and zlib, but I can't find any good examples of compressing such files in zlib.

Comment: Well you could run zip as ..\zip on Windows if zip.exe is in source's parent directory.

Comment: @IanAbbott in that case I get message from cmd: '..\zip' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: So where is zip.exe in your set-up in relation to the `source` (xlsx components) directory? Is it in your command PATH directories?

Comment: @IanAbbott no, it's not in my cmd PATH directories. zip.exe is simply located in it's project Debug folder. I understand, that I can add it to PATH, but the idea is different. I need some kind of algorithm to include into my project that can zip and unzip MS Office .xlsx and .docx-files to work with them (read, edit, save) without using Excel or Word. So, utilities like zip and unzip from Info-Zip do these things, but zip utility do this with described above problem.

Comment: I guess you should already know how to run a program that is not in the PATH and not in the current directory.

Comment: The solution was really near - it is enough to use such command: cd .\source
..\zip.exe -r -D ..\res.xlsx .